# Pros and cons of Xcode base internationalization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

What are pros and cons of using Xcode base internationalization?
Maybe it's easier to use just NSLocalizedString and set titles, labels, buttons in code?

Answer (score 0):

Base internalization is a much better idea than manually setting things in code. It is much less work both to implement originally and to maintain. You just add the .strings file for a language and then edit it to translate all the strings in your UI. With NSLocalizedString you have to do this as well, but in addition you need to write special code for every UI element with a string. If you add or remove a UI element, you need to write code again. Using NSLocalizedString is probably also less efficient at run time. Your app has to completely load the UI for your development language and then go through and change all the strings in the UI to the localized versions.

There really are not any cons to using base internalization except for legacy considerations:

- It requires iOS 6 or Mac OS X 10.8 or newer.
- Converting a legacy project with separate .xib or storyboard files for every language can be a pain since you need to convert to auto layout. (The string extraction can be done automatically by Xcode.)